# How to Set RUBYOPT on windows to use additional includes

Tags: ruby, windows, environment-variables

I am trying to change my RUBYOPT environment variable.

My aim is to use my own library, which is in C:\ruby_lib, so I do:

`echo set RUBYOPT="-I C:\ruby_lib\`

If I try to run my program, which contains only `require "dummy.rb"` all I get is `no such file to load`, which should not happen has long as `dummy.rb` can be found in `C:\ruby_lib`

I am wondering if there is something I am doing wrong when I set the RUBYOPT environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting the `RUBYOPT` environment variable. You are just `echo`ing the string `set RUBYOPT="-I C:\ruby_lib\` to the console.

Just remove the `echo`:

```
set RUBYOPT=-I C:\ruby_lib
```

Comment: Ok it works, thanks. How do you display the value of an environment variable in DOS ?

Comment: @jules: just `set RUBYOPT` will print the contents of the `RUBYOPT` variable (actually, *all* variables that *start with* `RUBYOPT`, I think) and `set` on its own will print them all.